# Шаблонизатор Blade в Laravel Как подключить много динамичных блоков

Tags: laravel, шаблонизаторы, blade

Всем привет, я понимаю возможно уже ответ есть на мой вопрос, но я не нашел. 
В общем логика такова, мне нужно собрать главную страницу которая будет состоять из нескольких динамичных блоков, например:

- блок последних постов
- блок последних фото
- блок последних видео итд.

Для каждого блока контент выбирается из бд, если подключить шаблоны например через @include() то понятное дело получим ошибку undefined variable в первом же блоке.

Второй вариант использовать в дочернем блоке @extends('parent'), а в родительском подключать через yeild('child'), но опять таки в одном блоке все нормально отработает, а во всех остальных undefined variable.

Как правильно формировать шаблон страницы в таком случае?

Единственное что приходит на ум - это подключить разделы через @include() и выбрать данные для всех блоков, после передать переменные в шаблон.

Comment: `@include('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])`